# Using kvm with WSL (Trying to run Android emulator using WSL)

Tags: android-studio, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kvm

I am running Android Studio from WSL. When I try to use the emulator I get `"/dev/kvm" not found`. I have installed kvm and I have confirmed that vt-x emulation is enabled in my BIOS.

Is it possible to use kvm with WSL (Ubuntu)?

Comment: https://boxofcables.dev/accelerated-kvm-guests-on-wsl-2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KVM only runs on an actual Linux kernel, not Windows Subsystem for Linux (which runs on a thin Linux emulation layer over the Windows kernel).

You can either run Android Studio on Linux natively, or use the Windows version of Android Studio (on Windows, only HAXM is supported).

Comment: what about WSL2 which runs on a real Linux kernel (latest LTS 4.19) in a light hyper-v vm?

Comment: @Wis That's a whole other can of worms, but it won't work either for different reasons.

Comment: Maybe it's time to take a stab at it again https://boxofcables.dev/accelerated-kvm-guests-on-wsl-2/